# Check the exam in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve this question:

> The first input array is the key to the correct answers to an exam, like `["a", "a", "b", "d"]`. The second one contains a student's submitted answers.
>
> The two arrays are not empty and are the same length. Return the score for this array of answers, giving +4 for each correct answer, -1 for each incorrect answer, and +0 for each blank answer, represented as an empty string (in C the space character is used).

I keep getting this error message for this code:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

And this is my code:

```
def check_exam(arr1, arr2):
    res = 0
    for i in arr1[i]:
        while arr2[i] != "":
            if arr2[i] == arr1[i]:
                res += 4
            else:
                res -= 1
    return res
    
print(check_exam(["a", "a", "b", "b"], ["a", "c", "b", "d"]))
```

Comment: Well, what do you expect `arr[i]` to be? `i` is not yet defined at that point. It is only accesible ***inside*** the loop. Did you mean `for i in range(len(arr1)):`?

Comment: It is not necessary to use two loops here. One is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the `for i in arr1[i]` as you are using `i` before having defined it.

I solved the problem in this way:

```
def check_exam(arr1, arr2):
    res = 0
    # As len(arr1) = len(arr2) I choose one of them.
    for i in range(len(arr1)):
        if arr1[i] == arr2[i]:
            res += 4
        elif arr2[i] == "":
            res += 0  # Blank answer.
        else:
            res -= 1
    return res

print(check_exam(["a","a","b","b"], ["a","c","b","d"]))
```

You can simply compare the elements of the two arrays that have the same index using `for i in range(len(<one of the two arrays>))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip`:

```
def check_exam(arr1, arr2):
    res = 0
    for i, j in zip(arr1, arr2):
        if i == j:
            res += 4
        elif i:
            res -= 1
    return res
    
print(check_exam(["a", "a", "b", "b"], ["a", "c", "b", "d"]))
```

Output:

```
6
```

Explanation:

The `zip` function takes in a number of iterables, and iterates through them side by side, instead of one at a time, allowing us to compare each element of the same index.

Comment: FWIW, you can make it a one-liner: `return sum(4 if i==j else -1 if i else 0 for i,j in zip(arr1, arr2))` The nested conditional expression is a little hard to read though. So you could replace `-1 if i else 0` with `-bool(i)`, but that's even harder to read.

Answer (score -1):

You are iterating wrong. It would be better to iterate via index instead of direct values since both the arrays have same length here.

```
def check_exam(arr1, arr2):
    res = 0
    for i in range(len(arr1)):
        if arr2[i] == arr1[i]:
            res += 4
        elif arr[2] == '':
            continue
        else:
            res -= 1
    return res


print(check_exam(["a", "a", "b", "b"], ["a", "c", "b", "d"]))
```

Comment: It would be even better to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score -1):

```
def check_exam(arr1, arr2):
res = 0
for i in range(len(arr1)):

    if arr1[i] != arr2[i]:

        if arr2[i] != "": res-=1
        else: res+=0 #Blank
    
    elif arr1[i] == arr2[i]: res+=4
if res<0:
    return 0

return res
```

This code also checks for if the result is less than 0, becuase in the codewars problem it does have some cases of the result going into the negative numbers, and it does want the result to be result as 0 for any negative number/result.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).